# Did Grindelwald and Voldemort use Fiendfyre?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In the 5th book, Voldemort creates a big flame that acted like a snake. In Crimes of Grindelwald, Grindelwald used Protego Diabolica to create those monster creatures nearly destroying Paris.

Is that the same spell Crabbe used?

Comment: [This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65929/fiendfyre-to-destroy-horcrux) partly answers your question

Comment: And [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207828/was-the-blue-fire-from-crimes-of-grindlewald-fiendfyre) answers the second part of your question

Comment: I don't know how this question can be marked as a dupe (since it involves two other questions)